# putting a trend line and r squared value in a graph

Tags: r

I made line graphs of two different scales and i want to draw two trend lines in each line graph and display r squared value in the graph. R squared value of temperature and Year, precipitation and year. I am also having problem on showing legend on the precipitation axis. Please help me fix it.

```
 library(lattice)
data=read.table("temp_pcp.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",")
frame=data.frame(data[1:3])
year <- data[1]
Temperature <- data[3]
Precipitation <- data[2]
gm<-data.frame(year,Temperature)
mg<-data.frame(year,Precipitation)
plot(gm, axes=FALSE, ylim=c(0,20), xlab="", ylab="", 
   type="l",col="black", main="Climograph")
axis(2, ylim=c(0,20),col="black",las=1)
mtext("Temperature in Degree Celcius ",side=2,line=2.5)
box()
grid()
par(new=TRUE)
plot(mg, xlab="", ylab="", ylim=c(0,60), 
    axes=FALSE, type="l", col="red")
mtext("Precipitation in mm",side=4,col="black",line=4) 
axis(4, ylim=c(0,60), col="black",col.axis="black",las=1)
axis(1,pretty(range(year),10))
mtext("Year",side=1,col="black",line=2.5)
legend("topleft",legend=c("Tempreature","Precipitation"),
  text.col=c("black","red"),col=c("black","red"))
```

The line graph i created is as follow;
[image]

Comment: what's in `"temp_pcp.csv"`

Comment: what kind of line? `lines(year, predict(loess(mg ~ year)))`, please make a reproducible example that reflects your data. also why is lattice relevant here? you can change the color of the axes which might make this less confusing

Comment: @rawr lattice is not useful for this graph, i loaded it for other things, but i am not sure why my y axis legend does not show up !!!

Comment: @Lira the right margin isn't big enough to plot text on `line=4`, increase it when you first call `plot` with `par(mar = c(5,4,2,5))` then `plot`. you might also want to use `line=2` or something smaller than 4